# How to Pivot on Multiple column on Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to pivot Spark dataframe on multiple columns, I am using Pivot function, but after I add 2 columns, it is giving error like overloaded parameter.

> This is the error I am getting after add the third column, overloaded
>   method value pivot with alternatives: (pivotColumn: String,values:
>   java.util.List[Any])org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDa‌​taset
>    (pivotColumn: String,values:
>   Seq[Any])org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset 
>   (pivotColumn: String)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
>   cannot be applied to (String, String, String)

Here's my work:

```
 val df_new=df.join(df1, df("Col1")<=>df1("col1") && df1("col2")<=> df("col2")).groupBy(df("Col6"))
                             .agg(
                                 sum(df("Col1")).alias("Col1"), 
                                 sum(df("Col2")).alias("Col2")  ,
                                 sum(df("Col3")).alias("Col3")  ,
                                 sum(df("Col4")).alias("Col4")  ,
                                 sum(df("Col5")).alias("Col5")  
                                 ).select(
                                         Amount,'Col1, 'Col2,'Col3,'Col4,'Col5
                                          )
```

--Pivot

```
val pivotdf=df_new.groupBy($"Col1").
                  pivot("Col1","Col2","Col3","col4")
```

I have to pivot on col1,Col2,col3,col4 and col5.Please guide me How can I do that.

Comment: can you paste the error stack trace here ?

Comment: This is the error I am getting after add the third column, 



**overloaded method value pivot with alternatives: (pivotColumn: String,values: java.util.List[Any])org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset <and> (pivotColumn: String,values: Seq[Any])org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset <and> (pivotColumn: String)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset cannot be applied to (String, String, String)**

Comment: There is no `pivot` in your code :)

Comment: i came across the same problem